# How do I make my discord bot send a message only if in my code a variable is equal to another?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently in the process of creating my first Discord bot.
In my code there are 2 variables and if they are equal, the bot should send a message in my Discord server.
So far I have written the following code, but I can't figure out how to make it work, or even if it is possible at all.
Here is my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

client.run('123123')

announcements1 = client.get_channel(123123)

v1 = 1
v2 = 2

async def on_ready():
    if v1 == v2:
    await announcements1.send('hello')
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so there are multiple problems here.

1.) `client.run(token)` must be at the bottom of the script
2.) You did not add any indentation on your if-statment
3.) You also forgot to add a decorator above the async `on_ready` function.

I have fixed all those problems for you. Try this:

```py
import discord

TOKEN = 'token here'
client = discord.Client()

v1 = 1
v2 = 2

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    announcements1 = client.get_channel(123123)
    if v1 == v2:
        await announcements1.send('hello')
    else:
        print("no")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the code still doesn't work. I've copied and pasted your answer and inserted the correct token and channel id but I get this error:
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Marco\Desktop\test3.py", line 13, in on_ready
    await announcements1.send('hello')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: I just edited the post, try the code now. If it doesn't work, then the most likely causes for your error is that the bot doesn't have access to the channel, it is a voice channel, you used a string ID instead of an int. Anyway, if it doesn't work, just put another comment so I can help.